# Number rule is not working on the Input of ANTD

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, antd

I am using Antd Forms and type: number is not working.

```
rules : {[
{type: number},
{len: 5}, // <<--- THIS ONE IS NOT WORKING
{max: 999} //<<< this one is working
]}
```

As you can see I am using the InputNumber I am trying to use Input too.

When I enter anything other then the number I want to get an error. Antd has this functionality but I am not able to use it.

NOTE: I do not want to use the onChange event handler and set the "validateStatus" to error.

NOTE: I also do not want to use the RegExp because our data is coming from JSON we do not hard code any values.

Any help will be very helpful. Thank you.

I am using "antd": "3.26.12" version and using the class component.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import {
  Form,
  Button,
  InputNumber,
  Input,  
  Row,
  Col,
} from 'antd';

class Demo extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
      }
    });
  };

  normFile = e => {
    console.log('Upload event:', e);
    if (Array.isArray(e)) {
      return e;
    }
    return e && e.fileList;
  };

  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    const formItemLayout = {
      labelCol: { span: 6 },
      wrapperCol: { span: 14 },
    };
    return (
      <Form {...formItemLayout} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

        <Form.Item label="InputNumber">
          {getFieldDecorator('input-number', { rule:[ {len : 5}]})(<InputNumber />)} //<<<<---
        </Form.Item>



        <Form.Item wrapperCol={{ span: 12, offset: 6 }}>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

const WrappedDemo = Form.create({ name: 'validate_other' })(Demo);

ReactDOM.render(<WrappedDemo />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: For anyone reading this, I've added a [solution to this exact problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66846503/5819046) that works without using the `getFieldDecorator()` function. It's frustrating that the `type=number` rule does not work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the right API (`rules` is an array of objects), please refer to [form docs](https://3x.ant.design/components/form/) and its examples, also, `len` is for strings and is useless in `InputNumber`, you might just use `max`:

```
<Form.Item label="InputNumber">
  {getFieldDecorator('input-number', {
    rules: [
      {
        type: 'number',
        max: 999,
        message: 'The input is not a number, max = 999'
      }
    ]
  })(<InputNumber />)}
</Form.Item>
```

[image: Edit magical-stallman-sjr73]

Comment: Thank you for your response. How can I achieve zip code input then? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Please just ask another question, is also has been asked many times

Comment: Thank you for the help but that is what I wanted to know how can I achieve that functionality without using onChange event handler.

Comment: @amy Check out my answer to a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65931903/3358589).  My example shows zip code validation. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

##### Maybe you can do it this way!

```
 <Form.Item
             label="phone"
              name="phone"
              rules={[
                { type: 'number',
                  max: 999,
                  min: 5,
                  message: "Min max validation error!",
                  transform(value) {
                    return Number(value)
                  },
                }
              ]}>
           <Input  key={2} />
            </Form.Item>
```