# Why number validate rule doesnt work in antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have a simple login form, but validation rule with `type: 'number'` for input item tn doesn't work. Even if I enter a number, I get `'tn' is not a valid number'` in console.

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import { Form, Input, Button, Checkbox } from 'antd';
    import { UserOutlined, LockOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
    import './style.css';
    
    export const LoginForm = () => {
      const onFinish = (values) => {
        console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
      };
    
      return (
        <Form
          name="login_form"
          className="login-form"
          initialValues={{
            remember: true,
          }}
          onFinish={onFinish}
        >
          <h3 className="main-label">LOG IN</h3>
          <Form.Item
            name="tn"
            rules={[
              {
                type: 'number',
                required: true,
                message: 'Wrong number',
              },
            ]}
          >
            <Input
              prefix={<UserOutlined className="site-form-item-icon" />}
              placeholder="Enter your tn"
            />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item
            name="password"
            rules={[
              {
                required: true,
                message: 'Please input your password',
              },
            ]}
          >
            <Input
              prefix={<LockOutlined className="site-form-item-icon" />}
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
            />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item>
            <Form.Item name="remember" valuePropName="checked" noStyle>
              <Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>
            </Form.Item>
          </Form.Item>
    
         ...
      );
    };
```

I tried other rules and they works fine. What's the problem with numbers?

Comment: if you need only number you can use "InputNumber" docs - https://ant.design/components/input-number/

Comment: @Will Black i dont need field with up and down arrows, especially when it must work out of the box with type: number, but it doesnt

Comment: @tzi0 I just updated my answer! There is a real solution now. [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editors=001&prefill_data_id=a025c248-17da-4340-abf6-eb6ac2f42037). If this helps, you can accept my answer for this question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to Ant Design's [`<Input/>`](https://ant.design/components/input/) component, it will store the number as a string even if the type props have been set.

The first workaround is to just use Ant Design's [`<Input Number/>`](https://ant.design/components/input-number/) component, which doesn't store the number as a string (AFAIK without looking at the source).
Although that component is quite nice, it does come with the arrows for adjusting the number, which isn't optimal if prompting for something like a zip code.

After further digging, whether it is a real bug or an overlook, `{type:number}` won't get you anywhere when using Ant Design's [`<Input/>`](https://ant.design/components/input/) component.

I would suggest you check out [Issue #731](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/731#issuecomment-517738264), then check out [Issue #10003](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/10003) for more details. (there is some pretty neat validation code in both of those like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/7wyorykwp0) ... but just browse around and explore).

I like the simplicity of just listing the rule sets without implementing a custom validator (especially for problems like number-only); however, it's not always possible.

Here is some sample code that I use for my Zip Code validation. Note that you could always combine the message strings into one `Promise.Reject()` at the end of the validator, but I find it clutters up the screen for the user (especially with more than two validation error messages).

```
<Form.Item
  validateTrigger="onBlur"
  name="ZipCode"
  label="Zip Code"
  hasFeedback
  rules={[
    {
      required: true,
      message: "Please enter zip code",
    },
    () => ({
      validator(_, value) {
        if (!value) {
          return Promise.reject();
        }
        if (isNaN(value)) {
          return Promise.reject("Zip code has to be a number.");
        }
        if (value.length < 5) {
          return Promise.reject("Zip code can't be less than 5 digits");
        }
        if (value.length > 5) {
          return Promise.reject("Zip code can't be more than 5 digits");
        }
        return Promise.resolve();
      },
    }),
  ]}
>
  <Input />
</Form.Item>;
```

**Edit:** Not exactly sure if I just overlooked this or if they recently put it up, but there is a working input (like you want) using custom validation. I believe this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editors=001&prefill_data_id=a025c248-17da-4340-abf6-eb6ac2f42037) will solve your problem.

Comment: Your CodePen link doesn't seem to work any more. As far as I can see, in v4 antd, there is still no easy solution to this. I'm amazed this is so difficult considering it's now native in HTML5.

Comment: OK, I've found a workaround using regex. I'm adding an answer now.

Comment: Cool. I remember when I answered this question, I found that CodePen on a GH issue if I am remembering correctly. I didn't own the CodePen.

Comment: Solving using regex would be a much better approach to be honest.

Comment: I spoke too soon, even the Regex doesn't work. Adding type="number" sorta' works but it's still not great.

Comment: I wish I could remember the solution in the CodePen.

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer with a working example. My Regex pattern was wrong, amongst other things.

Answer (score 6):

The built in method does not work as Ant Design v4 recognises inputs as string. The solution is to use Regex.

```
<Form.Item
    name="myNumber"
    rules={[{ 
        required: true, 
        message: "A value must be entered",
        pattern: new RegExp(/^[0-9]+$/)
    }]}
>
    <Input
        placeholder="x"
        maxLength={5}
    />
</Form.Item>
```

It's also worth noting that the `getFieldDecorator()` method is basically redundant as of v4 of Ant Design. They should also better advertise that.

The above Regex pattern enforces integers and disallows decimals.